# Struts2 dojo Anchor tag does not work?

Tags: java, struts2, dojo, struts

Tag `<sx:head />` is present on the page. I try to update content of div:

```
<div id="div1">
...
</div>

<s:url id="ajaxData" value="/ajaxData.action" />
<sx:a id="link1" href="%{ajaxData}" targets="div1">
update data
</sx:a>
```

action

```
public String execute() {
    ...
    return NONE;
}
```

xml

```
<action name="ajaxData" class="com.data.action.AjaxDataAction">
    <result name="none">/page.jsp</result>
</action>
```

But when I press **update data** the browser tab shows animation, it means that whole page updates? It reloads the whole page, not only div, I want to reload only div partially.

Comment: Struts2 dojo plugin is deprecated.

Comment: Take a look at Struts2-jQuery-plugin. Also note that the AJAX action should return a JSP snippet with a dispatcher result, an HTML snippet with a Stream result, or something like that. Returning NONE makes no sense.

Comment: Ok. I'll try Struts2-jQuery-plugin.