# Struts 2 ajax-plugin: updating div

Tags: java, ajax, struts2, struts

Acсording to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635385/struts2-dojo-anchor-tag-does-not-work)  question

I tried use of ajax-plugin for updating div. However, this example does not work as it should, it outputs nothing.

What is missing this time?

So, what we have.

*page:*

```
<div id="div1">
  <!-- ajax result ? -->

  <div>
      <s:iterator value="<s:property value='data1'/>">
      <s:property />
      <br />
      </s:iterator>
  </div>

</div>

<div>
  <s:url id="ajaxData" value="/AjaxData.action"/>
  <sj:a id="link1" href="%{ajaxData}" targets="div1">
  Update Content
  </sj:a>
</div>
```

*struts.xml:*

```
<action name="AjaxData" class="com.data.action.AjaxDataAction">
    <result name="success">/ajaxdata.jsp</result>
</action>
```

*action:*

```
public class AjaxDataAction extends ActionSupport {     
    private List<String> data1;    
    public String execute() {
        RandData data = new RandData();
        data1 = data.getData();
        return SUCCESS;
    }   

    public List<String> getData1() {
        return data1;
    }

    public void setData1(List<String> data1) {
        this.data1 = data1;
    }
}
```

and *ajaxdata.jsp*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<div>
    <s:iterator value="<s:property value='data1'/>">
        <s:property />
        <br />
    </s:iterator>
</div>
```

---

Update: execute() method does not starting.

Comment: You should not duplicate your linked question with the same problem, instead edit a question and add details. Post the errors you have, and what did you try to resolve them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts2 dojo Anchor tag does not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635385/struts2-dojo-anchor-tag-does-not-work)

Comment: There is no errors, _div1_ contains nothing. I tried put **data1** to session ang get it via session in _ajaxdata.jsp_, but result is the same.

Comment: That `<s:iterator value="<s:property value='data1'/>">` - will throw an exception. You can't nest tags like that.

Comment: For some reason that code does not throw an exception.

Comment: Fine. So how do you make it work?

Comment: Just `<s:iterator value="data1">`.

Comment: For some reason does not working and no errors. Div1 tag contains only empty inner div.

Comment: and execute() method does not starting too

Comment: Use `<s:url>` tag with `action="AjaxData"` attribute instead of `value`.

Comment: Also try referencing `ajaxData` with a leading `#`, e.g., `%{#ajaxData}`. This may depend on the S2 version you're using.

Comment: I'm using the latest S2 & ajax-plugin and I've tried that all - nothing.

Comment: Can you please make up your question with a complete `struts.xml` with `package` element and also a complete entire `JSP`, because in the presented snippet I did not find a taglib declaration `<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>` for Struts 2 jQuery tags?